# permutations of a string algorithm analysis

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, permutation

I have two algorithms for printing the permutations of a string

Here is the 1st one.

```
#include<iostream>

int fact(int f)
{
   if(f == 0)
      return 1;
  return f*fact(f-1);
}
int main()
{   
   char A[] = "abc";
   int size = strlen(A);
   int per = fact(size);  // per is the number of permutations we will get

   int j = 0;   // j is the index of the elements of A we will swap

   // this is the algorithm
   for(int i=1;i<=per;i++)
   {   
      cout << A << endl;
      if(j == size-1)
         j = 0;
      swap(A[j],A[j+1]);
      j++;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the 2nd one.

```
// C program to print all permutations of the input string

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function to swap values at two pointers 
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{    
   char temp = *x;
   *x = *y;
   *y = temp;
}

// Function to print permutations of string
This function takes three parameters:
1. String
2. Starting index of the string or sub-string
3. Ending index of the string 

void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
  int i;
  if (l == r)
     printf("%s\n", a);
  else
  {
     for(i = l; i <= r; i++)
     {  
        swap((a+l), (a+i));
        permute(a, l+1, r);
        swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack to retain the original string
     }
  }
}

int main()
{
  char str[50];

  gets_s(str);

  int n = strlen(str);
  permute(str, 0, n-1);

  return 0;
}
```

According to me...both should perform the same....and they in fact do....but only for small inputs..eg: "abc" , "abcd".But when the string becomes large..eg:
"abcdefghi"..the first one takes a hell of a lot of time as opposed to second one.

Im having a tough time analysing why the second one performs better than the first.Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: I'd look at the fact function as the culprit. Did you try to calculate the factorial of a number larger than 10? 15? 20?

Comment: Make your fact function use a loop instead of recursion and check it again.  
If it is faster there is your problem.

Comment: Which language are you using? Please compare like with like.

Comment: im using c and c++

Comment: i dont think fact is a problem,becoz first i compute the factorial....and only then the printing starts...and the printing is taking a lot of time if you try and run the code

Answer (score 0):

Just add below statement in you main function before you start printing:

```
std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);
```

This disables the synchronization with the standard `C-streams` for every IO operation.

Read more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)

Comment: @user5422891 By 'not working', do you mean that your C program outperforms the C++ code ? I was able to reproduce that and after adding this, the C++ code ran faster than the C version. I used the linux `time` command to measure the total time.

Comment: yes...the C one still outperforms the C++ one....when i input "abcdefghi" the C++ doesnt seem to finish at all...the C one finishes in 15 secs....i didnt measure the time though...just an approximation

Comment: i used printf in the C++ code instead of cout....and now the C and C++ both finish on the same time....it takes 20 secs for input "abcdefghi".Is printf more efficient than cout??If yes...why so??

Comment: @user5422891 Which compiler do you use ? and which platform ? C++ streams though I agree is somewhat badly designed but should not be any slower than C printf. Almost always disabling `sync_with_stdio`  solves this kind of performance issue. Can you also update your C++ code as well ?

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2015 community on windows 10

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you there. Don't have a windows OS with me. If you can check in Mac/linux that would be great. If you find performance improvement in *nix platform, then it is probably an implementation issue of iostreams in VS.